# How can I divide a set of strings into subsets of fixed size with maximal homogeneity?

Tags: greedy-algorithms, string-metrics

Suppose I have a set of 1000 binary strings of fixed length. I wish to divide these 1000 strings into 10 subsets of 100 strings each, in such a way that the subsets are maximally homogeneous. I want each subset of 100 to be as internally similar as possible. Similarities between subsets of 100 are of no consequence.

I believe the best way to quantify homogeneity for my purposes is with [simple matching coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_matching_coefficient). A straightforward greedy algorithm to define the subsets appears to be $O(n^2)$, but I'm not convinced this finds the optimal result. Is there proof either way? Is there another algorithm I should consider? Another homogeneity metric?

The resulting algorithm needs to be polynomial time.

Comment: 1. I don't understand how you plan to measure the homogeneity of a proposed solution.  The simple matching coefficient apparently provides a way to compute a score for any pair of strings, but how do you plan to use that to get a score for a proposed solution?  Do you plan to sum over all pairs of strings that are placed in the same subset?  2. Can you clarify how simple matching coefficient is applied to binary strings?  It's defined in terms of a bunch of attributes; is there an obvious extension to binary strings?  Is it basically equivalent to the hamming distance between the two strings?

Comment: 3. This sounds like a [clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).  Have you read about clustering?  See also the [graph partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) and the [metric k-center problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center).  4. Probably the problem is NP-hard, so you should decide how you want to deal with that.